# How to make qtip2 tooltips dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, qtip2

When the page loads every tooltip is working perfectly fine but when the data refreshes through ajax then it just stop working how can i make it work??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // MAKE SURE YOUR SELECTOR MATCHES SOMETHING IN YOUR HTML!!!
    $('.userExtend').each(function() {

        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: function(event, api) {
                    $.ajax({
                            url: api.elements.target.attr('data-url') // Use href attribute as URL
                        })
                        .then(function(content) {
                            // Set the tooltip content upon successful retrieval
                            api.set('content.text', content);
                        }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                            // Upon failure... set the tooltip content to error
                            api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
                        });

                    return 'Loading...'; // Set some initial text
                }
            },
            position: {
                viewport: $(window)
            },
            hide: {
                fixed: true,
                delay: 300
            },
            style: 'qtip-light'
        });
    });
});
```

According qtip2 here is how we can make it dynamic http://jsfiddle.net/qTip2/qcwV4/ but I'm new to jquery & unable to integrate it with this code

Answer (score 2):

What the qTip fiddle suggest is a socalled [**delegated event handler**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). The trick is to attach a `mouseenter` handler to a parent element but delegate the event to descendants by the use of a selector - in the fiddle all `<a>` tags with a `title` attribute `a[title]`.

You can easily adapt this approach to your own code. You want to bind qTips to any element which has the class `.userExtend` :

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.userExtend', function() {
  $(this).qtip({
    content: {
      text: function(event, api) {
        $.ajax({
            url: api.elements.target.attr('data-url') // Use href attribute as URL
          })
          .then(function(content) {
            // Set the tooltip content upon successful retrieval
            api.set('content.text', content);
          }, function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Upon failure... set the tooltip content to error
            api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
          });

        return 'Loading...'; // Set some initial text
      }
    },
    position: {
      viewport: $(window)
    },
    hide: {
      fixed: true,
      delay: 300
    },
    style: 'qtip-light'
  });
});
```

Notice the lack of a `ready()` handler; it is not necessary and should [generally be avoided](http://modernweb.com/2013/05/06/5-things-you-should-stop-doing-with-jquery/).